# CouchDB replicate in order to clone my DB into a new instance

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, couchdb

I am working on replicating my DB into another instance of CouchDB. To test it, I've created two Docker images, one containing some sample data and the other one serving as an empty instance. The DB with the test data is running on `localhost:5984`, while the target instance I want to replicate the data into is available at `localhost:5985`.

Here is my code my code:

```
const replicateTest = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5984/_replicate",
      {
        source: `http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/test_1`,
        target: `http://admin:admin@localhost:5985/test_1`,
        create_target: true,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

This is the error that I am getting as a response:
`{ error: 'invalid_json', reason: '{1,invalid_json}' }`

Here are a list of tests that I was trying to conduct:

1. In order to ensure my servers were running correctly, I queried them using the following code, which worked successfully. It confirmed that there are no connectivity issues:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(
    "http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/_all_dbs"
);
```

2. I've changed the post request many time and got the same result. Here are some of the variations I tried:

   - I experimented with passing the full path to the post request, such as `http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/_replicate`.
   - Passing a `curl` request insted of my `axios` request.
   - I tested using the IP `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.
   - I referred to [CouchDB's documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/common.html#post--_replicate), without much of a success.
3. When using this syntax:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5984/_replicate",
      {
        source: `http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/test_1`,
        target: {
          url: "http://localhost:5985/test_1",
          auth: {
            basic: {
              username: "admin",
              password: "admin",
            },
          },
        },
        create_target: true,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
```

I am getting this error:

```
 data: {
      error: 'replication_auth_error',
      reason: '{session_request_failed,"http://localhost:5985/_session","admin",\n' +
        '                        {conn_failed,{error,econnrefused}}}'
    }
```

I am including my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  couchdb1:
    image: couchdb:latest
    container_name: my-couchdb1
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: admin
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./data1:/opt/couchdb/data

  couchdb2:
    image: couchdb:latest
    container_name: my-couchdb2
    ports:
      - "5985:5984"
    environment:
      COUCHDB_USER: admin
      COUCHDB_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./data2:/opt/couchdb/data
```

Comment: For #3, the credentials are both in the URL and the request header. I don't know if that is a problem, but it is questionable.

Comment: Which version of couch are you running?

Comment: @smathy 
latest version:
latest, 3.3.2, 3.3, 3

Comment: Hmm, I asked because this [was definitely an issue in older versions](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1550) - but was fixed. Maybe a regression (you could try the workarounds in that ticket).

Comment: @smathy Based on the documentation, this task seemed quite straightforward. But, I'm finding it challenging to pinpoint the problem. It's either a new bug, or there's some aspect I'm not fully grasping. For now, I've hit a standstill in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on resolving the issues with CouchDb's `_replicate` method, but, I've managed to create a temporary solution that, while not ideal, gets the job done.
This approach involves a script that duplicates each database from the source to the target, followed by coping each document.

I am using `lodash`, `nano`, and `process` as dependencies for this process.

Please see the script below:

```
const sourceUrl = argv[2] ?? "http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/";
const targetUrl = argv[3] ?? "http://admin:admin@localhost:5985/";

const sourceDb = nano(sourceUrl);
const targetDb = nano(targetUrl);

const databasesReplicate = async () => {
  try {
    const allSourceDbs = await sourceDb.db.list();

    allSourceDbs.map(async (dbName) => {
      const isDbExistsResponse = await isDbExists(dbName);
      await createDb({ db: isDbExistsResponse, dbName });
      const docsData = await getAllDocs(dbName);

      const targetDbScope = targetDb.use(dbName);

      await Promise.allSettled(
        docsData.map(async (docData) => {
          if (docData.doc) {
            await insertDocument(docData.doc, targetDbScope);
          }
        })
      );
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const isDbExists = async (dbName: string) => {
  return await targetDb.db.get(dbName).catch((err) => {
    if (err.statusCode === 404) {
      return null;
    }

    throw err;
  });
};

const createDb = async ({ db, dbName }: CreateDbInterface) => {
  if (!db) {
    await targetDb.db.create(dbName);
    console.info(`database '${dbName}' created in the target CouchDB.`);
  }

  console.log(dbName)
};

const getAllDocs = async (dbName: string) =>
  (await sourceDb.use(dbName).list({ include_docs: true })).rows;

const insertDocument = async (doc: Document, db: DocumentScope<unknown>) => {
  const selector = {
    selector: {
      _id: { $eq: doc._id },
    },
    limit: 1,
  };

  const existingData = await findOneDocByFilter({ db, selector });
  const docToInsert = omit(doc, "_rev");

  return existingData
    ? await db.insert({ ...docToInsert, _rev: existingData._rev })
    : await db.insert(docToInsert);
};

const findOneDocByFilter = async ({ db, selector }: FindByInterface) => {
  try {
    const { docs } = await db.find(selector);
    return docs.length ? docs[0] : null;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```